# Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 debug Console cannot display correctly chinese

Tags: visual-studio, character-encoding, visual-studio-2022

I really didn't expect that the visual studio 2022 version could not display Chinese correctly! I used JetBrains Rider before. It has a built-in console. When running, it will always display Chinese correctly, just like VSCode's built-in terminal.

I know it must be because the character code the code is running on doesn't match the terminal's settings. But this should not be manually modified by the user. . .

my code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
// here does not work
// output: ??,??!
Console.WriteLine("你好，世界！");
```

output:
[image: console output]

extra information：

- my operating system: windows 10
- windows terminal as defautl terminal
- **Visual Studio uses "windows console host" as the default console, it doesn't seem to support utf-8. (I have set windows terminal as default terminal)**
- When I set the default terminal to "Windows Console Host", right-click to view the character encoding of the terminal:
  [image: Windows console host]
  [image: character encoding of the console]

Maybe replacing the default console of visual studio with powershell can solve the problem?

---

thank you all

Answer (score 2):

I found a temporary solution (as one line of code needs to be added):

In my case (windows 10), Visual Studio uses a console called "Windwos Console Host" as the default terminal, which doesn't seem to support utf-8

because when I added the following code:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

**the Chinese output changed from "question mark" to "strange symbols"**, so I deduce that the terminal used by Visual Studio Debug Console probably does not support UTF-8:

[image: console output]

So I changed the default terminal to "windows terminal" in the settings of "windows terminal":

[image: windows terminal setting]

This time successfully printed Chinese ("windows terminal" must support utf-8):

[image: console output]

Comment: 老哥，我用visual studio 2022也出现在终端打印的时候是乱码的情况，这个`So I changed the default terminal to "windows terminal" in the settings of "windows terminal":` 设置在哪啊？我没找到啊。

Comment: @Tom windows terminal -> "Startup" -> "Default terminal application" -> 最后选择"Windows terminal"

Comment: I done it. Thank you very much.